# undefined method `prouct_price?' for class OrderItems--(OrderItemsController#create)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cart

```js
  CreateOrderItems Migration
  def change
    create_table :order_items do |t|
      t.integer :product_id
      t.integer :order_id
      t.decimal :unit_price
      t.integer :p_quantity
      t.decimal :total_price

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

```css
 OrderItemsController
  def create
  @order = current_order
  @order_item =               @order.order_items.new(order_item_params)
  @order.save
  session[:order_id] = @order.id
 end
   def order_item_params
  params.require(:order_item).permit(:product_id, :p_quantity)
 end
```

```html
 OrderItem Model
  belongs_to :product
  def unit_price
  if persisted?
   self[:unit_price]
  else
   Product.product_price?
  end
 end
```

I have defined association, but Create method of OrderItem is unable to fetch product_id. Product has many order item relation, please answer, what mistake i'm doing..?
Thank you

```js
create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "product_title"
    t.text "key_features"
    t.decimal "product_price"
    t.string "colour"
    t.string "main_material"
    t.integer "product_quantity"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Comment: Can you show definition for `product_price? `?

Comment: Please share Product controller with product_price? method.

Comment: def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:product_title, :key_features, :product_price, :colour, :main_material, :product_quantity)
  end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a simple spelling error.
In the method `unit_price` of OrderItem Model, you are using `Product.prouct_price` .

Instead of that you should use `product.product_price`. First error was of spelling mistake and second error is because you are using `Product` instead of `product` for using associated product to OrderItem.

Also, I am unable to understand that why have you kept `unit_price` and `total_price` in table of OrderItem as you can dynamically evaluate or figure out that value using associations and simple math. So, according to me it is unnecessary to make colums for these values.

Comment: Hi @Akash Gupta i changed the mistakes highlight by you, but error still remains. The reason why i used unit_price and total_price is that, unit price holds the price of added product  to cart and total price for More than 1 product adding again and again,#total_price=p_quantity*unit_price

Comment: Can you add schema of products table to the question?

Comment: added, check it now

Comment: Also add full stack trace of error. Otherwise our answers will be nothing more than a guess.

Comment: @Wasi For your explanation of keeping unit_price in db, you are using a method `unit_price` in model of OrderItem to find its unit price using product price of Product and then sinply multiplying it by quantity to get total_price, that is why I'm telling you that it can be done by computation only on runtime instead of saving it in db. You need only quantity to save in db for OrderItem and not item_price or total_price.